# From a list of dictionaries, create one dictionary which members contain a list

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

Having the following list of dictionaries:

```
  - set_fact:
      inventory:
        - dn: host1
          lid: 0021-00
          unit_id: 50
        - dn: host2
          lid: 1011-00
          unit_id: 50
        - dn: host2
          lid: 1004-00
          unit_id: 50
```

Iterating over that list I'd like to create a new
dictionary as like (dn becomes key and lid becomes list value):

```
  - set_fact:
      dn2lid:
        host1:
          - 0021-00
        host2:
          - 1011-00
          - 1004-00
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dn2lid: "{{ dn2lid|default({})|combine({item.0: lids}) }}"
      loop: "{{ inventory|groupby('dn') }}"
      vars:
        lids:  "{{ item.1|map(attribute='lid')|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: dn2lid
```

gives

```yaml
  dn2lid:
    host1:
    - 0021-00
    host2:
    - 1011-00
    - 1004-00
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vladimir. Your code works perfectly!